# "package ‘mgcv’ could not be loaded" only in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm getting this error when trying to load the package "TSA" in RStudio:

```
Loading required package: leaps
Loading required package: locfit
locfit 1.5-9.1   2013-03-22
Loading required package: mgcv
Loading required package: nlme
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'mgcv', details:
  call: formatDL(nm, txt, indent = max(nchar(nm, "w")) + 3)
  error: incorrect values of 'indent' and 'width'
Error: package ‘mgcv’ could not be loaded
```

I tried reinstalling mgcv and TSA, but it didn't help. However, when I load TSA from the R command line, it works without problem.

How can I fix this issue?

R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)

RStudio 0.97.551, 64 bits.

**UPDATE**:

I tested this issue in a 32 bit installation of RStudio and it worked flawlessly. I'm not sure what is the real culprit here.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the mgcv package. Did you try just installing the latest version of mgcv and then typing library(mgcv)?

Comment: I used RStudio utilities to install mgcv and it picked up an updated version. However, it showed exactly the same error. The same happens if I use the command line to install mgcv.

Comment: Since it is complaining of 'indent' and 'width' values, I'm wondering if you altered plot window settings at all? If so, you may also want to try resetting plot window settings back to default values and then retrying the install.

Comment: I haven't changed plot window settings at all. Actually, I reinstalled R since I had an older version. However, if you think this could be the issue, how can I do that in linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.

I had to remove rstudio via `sudo apt-get --purge remove rstudio` and remove `~/.config/RStudio`. Oddly enough, this didn't remove everything because some opened documents remained when I reinstalled RStudio. However, it did the trick.

```
> library(TSA)
Loading required package: leaps
Loading required package: locfit
locfit 1.5-9.1   2013-03-22
Loading required package: mgcv
Loading required package: nlme
This is mgcv 1.7-26. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
Loading required package: tseries

    ‘tseries’ version: 0.10-32

    ‘tseries’ is a package for time series analysis and
    computational finance.

    See ‘library(help="tseries")’ for details.


Attaching package: ‘TSA’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    acf, arima

The following object is masked from ‘package:utils’:

    tar
```

**UPDATE**:

Unfortunately, every time I restart RStudio, I get the same error as before. So this is only a temporary solution. Suggestions?

**UPDATE 2**:

Ultimately, this issue seems to have been resolved. I removed `~/.rstudio-desktop/monitored/user-settings/` and the problem immediately was solved without requiring reinstalling RStudio.

Comment: I removed ~/.rstudio-desktop/monitored/user-settings/
==> This seems to be for Mac. Do you know what the counterpart for Windows is?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what is the equivalent for Windows.

Answer (score 20):

In RStudio, just resize the right side to increase the width of the windows. Now try `library(mgcv)` again, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

For the reference of anyone encountering a similar problem under Windows 7, I had the same problem with the `forecast` package - one day, it just wouldn't load in RStudio (worked fine in R). Had to completely uninstall both R and RStudio, making sure to delete `C:\Program Files\R` and `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop` and reinstall before it would work again. Wouldn't work if I just deleted the RStudio stuff and tried to keep the R files.