# Unable to attache the library "gbm" to the R project

Tags: r, package, gbm

I installed the library `gbm` (RStudio). When I try to call it, it fails:

```
library("gbm")
Loading required package: survival
Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: parallel
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'gbm', details:
  call: formatDL(nm, txt, indent = max(nchar(nm, "w")) + 3)
  error: incorrect values of 'indent' and 'width'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘gbm’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gbm’
```

It should be mentioned that this library worked perfectly just one day ago. I haven't made any changes in the RStudio setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an odd error. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086111/package-mgcv-could-not-be-loaded-only-in-rstudio), which reported a similar problem with the `mgcv` R package; surpizingly, the solution seems to be to just resize the right side to increase the width of the windows. Now try to load the library ("gbm") again, and it should work.

Comment: In RStudio, just resize the right side to increase the width of the windows. Now try to load the library (gbm) again.